# Should I use the same character set in all tables and columns?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a social network and I decided to use utf8mb4 for user comments so that users can use smileys in their texts (MySQL-Engine: InnoDB).

I have set mysql server parameters to utf8mb4 and also the connection charset to utf8mb4.

Should I now use utf8mb4 instead of just utf8 in every single table and column of my database (for the username for example, even though I do not allow these characters in the username)?

Comment: I'd say the best way to answer the question is to look at how many other questions/problems around here result from the subtle way differing collations cause problems, and decide if the benefits of varied character sets outweigh the potential pitfalls opened up.